# How to pass variables from HTML to Javascript for debugging and release

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I am building and debugging the application through VSCode and live-server, and I am hosting the application on a local XAMPP apache server.

I would like to keep the javascript code the same and just switch between live-server and apache

the way I see doing this is by keeping an `index.html` for apache and `debug.html` for live-server in VSCode

So in index.html I would have something like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="main_div" style="position: relative; "></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js">
        bbCSV = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/BB.csv';
        smtCSV = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/SMT.csv';
    </script>    
</body>
```

Where `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` represents the IP of the server

And in debug.html I would have this

```
<body>
    <div id="main_div" style="position: relative; "></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js">
        bbCSV = 'http://localhost:8080/BB.csv';
        smtCSV = 'http://localhost:8080/SMT.csv';
    </script>    
</body>
```

But these variables do not work in the javascript file, presumably because they are created after main.js is parsed.

Is there a way to create the variables before the JavaScript file is loaded?

Or is there a better suggested way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

When you use a script tag with a `src` all the script inside will be ovewritten by the loaded script.

Try this:

```
<body>
  <div id="main_div" style="position: relative"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    bbCSV = "http://localhost:8080/BB.csv";
    smtCSV = "http://localhost:8080/SMT.csv";
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the chrome extension to launch a debugger session, or you can type ‘debugger’ into your code and open debugger tools to pause your script

[vscode Chrome Debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code)

Also, load your variables first then the JS file. Things run synchronously, so your file does not see those when it loads.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

const bbCSV = 'http://localhost:8080/BB.csv';
const smtCSV = 'http://localhost:8080/SMT.csv';

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```